# Code optimization for a minimization problem in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I need to find the parameters that minimize a function and here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import iv
from scipy.optimize import minimize

sqrt = np.sqrt
cos = np.cos
pi = np.pi
factorial = np.math.factorial

dd = 0.14
r0 = 5
Ur = -7

le = 20

def A(x,n):
    U4 = Ur
    U5 = x[3]
    U6 = x[4]   
    U7 = 0

    lr = x[0]
    lc1 = x[1]
    lc2 = x[2]

    z8 = dd + lc2 + dd + lc1 + dd + lr + le
    z9 = z8 + dd
    z10 = z9 + lc1
    z11 = z10 + dd
    z12 = z11 + lc2
    z13 = z12 + dd

    Z0 = lr/2 + dd + lc1 + dd + lc2 + dd
    d_char = sqrt((Z0**2+r0**2/2)/2)
    L = Z0+le

    kn = n*pi/(2*L)
    S1 = (U5-U4)/(kn**2*dd)*(cos(kn*(z9-L))-cos(kn*(z8-L)))
    S2 = (U6-U5)/(kn**2*dd)*(cos(kn*(z11-L))-cos(kn*(z10-L)))
    S3 = (U7-U6)/(kn**2*dd)*(cos(kn*(z13-L))-cos(kn*(z12-L)))
    S = S1+S2+S3

    return (2/(L*iv(0,kn*r0))*S,L,d_char)

def C(x,j):
    S = 0
    for k in range(1,40000,2):
        L = A(x,k)[1]
        d_char = A(x,k)[2]
        S = S + (k*pi/(2*L))**j*A(x,k)[0]
    return 2*d_char**j*(-1)**(j/2)/(Ur*factorial(j))*S

def optim_func(x):
    f = C(x,4)**2+C(x,6)**2+C(x,8)**2+C(x,10)**2
    return f

lr = 1.0
lc1 = 2.0
lc2 = 3.0
Uc1 = -7.0
Uc2 = -6.0

x0 = [lr,lc1,lc2,Uc1,Uc2]
res = minimize(optim_func, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
print(res.x)
```

I know the solution for this case (I just want to make sure that my code is working) and the initial values are close to the ones I need (that minimize the function). However, the code has been running for almost 2 hours. Did I do something wrong and somehow it entered an infinite loop? Or is there a way to optimize it to make it run faster? I will need to find the minima for cases where I don't know where to start so I expect those cases to take much longer than this one. Thank you!

Comment: Your `optim_func` is doing 1,440,000 multiplications/divisions, 880,000 exponentiations, 960,000 cosines, and 160,000 sqrt calls every time it is called, and the optimizer has to call that function over and over to find the zeros.  It is always going to take a very long time.

Comment: Optimization step one is to call `A(x,k)` once in the loop and reuse the values, instead of calling in 3 times, but that loop of 20,000 calls is going to kill you.